Deadlock possible in Minefield?
A deadlock is a position in which neither player has won and neither player has a legal placement available.  My question is, "Can you find a deadlock position in Minefield?"  And, if you can't, "Can you prove that a deadlock can't happen?"
Minefield rule sheet


Note that a legal move in Nakatta is always a legal move in Minefield. Nakatta has been proven to have no deadlocks: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126512/are-draws-possible-in-the-game-nakatta
